# how to properly get product base image without heavy lifting requests?

Tags: magento2, image

In magento2, I am using this function to get base image for product, but when products are more than 1k performance is awful.

In this code `_galleryHandler` is `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler` and `$_product` is product item from collection

```
protected function _getProductBaseImage($_product)
{

    $this->_galleryReadHandler->execute($_product);
    $imageUrl = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getFirstItem()->getUrl();

    return $imageUrl;
}
```

What is more efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: What class is this from?

Comment: this is my custom api code, in which base image should be obtained. I tried couple methods of image getting in magento2 and found this one most performant (got it from block code in product view or something like this). Maybe more performant options exist ? this is taking way to much time, for example 3k products without image iterating for 2s and with image 12s